# WP Footer Menu Not working?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been working on a site to change from HTML To Wordpress CMS...so got completed everything...Now stuck in one problem..and that is that I have declared the Main Navigation and Footer Navigation correctly (according to me) in functions.php file as :

```
/* Register Nav Main Menu */
register_nav_menus (array('main-nav' => 'Main Navigation'));
register_nav_menus (array('footer-nav' => 'Footer Navigation'));
```

while I am calling the both menus in correct way as for main-nav I am calling it in header.php as :

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'main-nav' ));
```

while calling the footer-nav as following in footer.php as :

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'footer-nav' ));
```

but in both places only main-nav is shown...so what did I do wrong please?..Need a hand to fix it...!

Waiting for your replies..!

Here is live link to the site as : http://www.huntedhunter.com/minaterra/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try changing:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'footer-nav' ));
```

to

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'footer-nav' ));
```

Comment: Thanks..Bro..It Worked..How you recognized that? Or How it works then?